# Nested vertical and horizontal lists?

Tags: html, css, nested-lists

I'm trying an html/css experiment where everything and all formatting is accomplished with unformatted lists (list-style-type:none). What I want to do is to be able to embed (to any degree) a vertical list in a horizontal list and vice-versa. So far I can embed a horizontal list (li ... display:inline;) in a vertical list and it works, but I can't seem to make a vertical list display as truly vertical inside a horizontal list.

Here's my CSS code so far:

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
body {  margin: 0px;  color:#333; }
ul.mainlist {  list-style-type:none;  margin: 0px; }
.mainlist li {  margin:0px; padding:0px;  }
ul.horizontallist {  list-style-type:none; margin: 0px;  padding:0px; }
.horizontallist li { margin:0px; padding:0px; display: inline-block; }
ul.secondlist { list-style-type:none; margin: 0px; padding:0px; }
.secondlist li { margin:0px; padding:0px;}
```

And my html:

```
<body>
    <ul class="mainlist">
      <li>
        <ul class="horizontallist">
          <li>
            <ul class="secondlist">
              <li>First in second vertical list.</li>
              <li>Second in second vertical list.</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>the snow in Alaska.</li>
          <li>the rain in Spain.</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Part of Mainlist</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

So far the "secondlist" isn't behaving as a vertical list inside the horizontal. Any ideas? Basically, I'd like to have most of my web design as lists of lists of lists so that I can begin to think of a DSL to handle it. I know lots of DSL exist already for html/css markup, but I'd like to gain control of the css side of things.

Answer (score 0):

I would say a `display:block` would work

```
.secondlist li { margin:0px; padding:0px; display:block;}
```

and another thing, because you set the margin and the padding to 0px in the universal selector, (*) it is not necessary to do in any other place, unless you want a different margin/padding.

Comment: Thanks Andres. That helped. But would there be a way to have the continuation of the "horizontallist" flush against the top? With your suggestion I've got "the snow in Alaska." and "the rain in Spain." continuing next to "Second in second vertical list." I'd like them up at the top next to "First in second vertical list." appearing like a quasi-drop-down menu embedded in a horizontal list.

Comment: I understand what you say, but I don't know if this is possible. It might be possible, but I don't know how to do it. I would use divs but you say you just want to use lists. To sum up, I dont know.

Comment: If I shove a few <br /> like this "<li>Second in horizontal list.<br /><br /><br />With extra text.</li>" it does in fact move the vertical list up. But that's a rather ugly kludge.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you meant.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
body {color:#333;}
ul.mainlist, ul.mainlist ul {list-style-type:none;}
ul.mainlist li, ul.horizontallist {display:inline-block;vertical-align:top}
ul.secondlist li {display:block}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<body>
<ul class="mainlist">
        <li>
                <ul class="horizontallist">
                        <li>
                                <ul class="secondlist">
                                        <li>First in second vertical list.</li>
                                        <li>Second in second vertical list.</li>
                                        <li>Third in second vertical list.</li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>the snow in Alaska.</li>
                        <li>the rain in Spain.</li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Part of Mainlist</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```